# Changes to imported scss file not triggering rebuild

Tags: angular, sass

I have an Angular 8 project with multiple libraries. My `my-common` library holds all my components.

One of the component folders in this library is structured as follows:

- sidebars

  - settings-sidebar

    - `settings-sidebar.component.ts`
    - `settings-sidebar.component.scss`
    - ...
  - detail-sidebar

    - ...
  - `sidebars.scss`

All my sidebars import the `sidebars.scss` in their `.scss` file by using `@import "../sidebars";`. This works as expected. All my styles in the `sidebars.scss` are available in my sidebar components.

The problem is, that any changes made to the `sidebars.scss` are not applied once the project is built and listening for changes.

The changes are detected, since I get this message in the terminal:

```
File change detected. Starting incremental compilation...

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Built Angular Package!
 - from: /app/projects/my-common
 - to:   /app/dist/my-common
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Compilation complete. Watching for file changes...
```

but they are not visible in the browser until I change something in the `.scss` files of the sidebar components or completely rebuild the project.

I am at my wits end and have no idea what could be causing this.

Comment: Do you have the actual CSS written in the imported file? Or you keep only the mixins/variables/etc. inside of it?